# How to auto fill a field by previous record value?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, autofill

[image]In my customized module,there is a field called closing_balance of type float.closing balance is calculated by total_credit - total_debit.I want to auto fill the field opening_balance of type float by the value of closing_balance when that particular employee creating next record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override *default_get* method of that object.

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    res = super(hr_expense_expense, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)

    #here is your logic
    opening_balance = 111 #do calculation as per your requirements

    #update opening balance field 
    res.update({'openning_balance_field_name': opening_balance})

    return res
```

Comment: No need to calculate the opening_balance.Opening balance should be auto fill by the value of previous closing_balance when employee creating next record.